# Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "("

Tags: symfony, twig, href

I am returning this error when I try to give the href into a twig file ---

Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "(" ("end of print statement" expected) in myBundle:Settings:settings.html.twig at line 53

**Twig :**

```
{% for usr in userStats %}
{<td>
<a href="{{ '/settings/management/aptid/{id}' ('myBundle_apt',{ aptId: usr.publisherId }) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOnbutton">ON</a>
</td>}
```

**Controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/settings/management/aptid/{id}", name="myBundle_apt")
 * @ParamConverter("apt", class="myBundle:UserStats")
 */
public function publishiddAction($id) {
    if (null !== ($request->get('myOnbutton'))) {
    
        $statss = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('myBundle:UserStats')
                ->findBy(array('aptId' => $id));
        }
    
        return $statss;
    
    return new Response("");
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this the right action? It seems you are not rendering any template in that one: the action does not have a `@Template` annotation nor it returns a `$this->render(<template path>)`.

Comment: I'll be blunt: I think you need to learn more about Symfony and Twig because you are doing a lot of simple mistakes that can be avoided by simply reading the official documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Twig is incorrect, you don't need `{`

I think you need to look at the [documentation of twig](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html)

### Change

```
{% for usr in userStats %}
{<td>
<a href="{{ '/settings/management/aptid/{id}' ('myBundle_apt',{ aptId: usr.publisherId }) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOnbutton">ON</a>
</td>}
```

### To

```
{% for usr in userStats %}
    <td>
        <a href="{{ path('myBundle_apt', { 'aptId': usr.publisherId }) }}"
       class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOnbutton">ON</a>
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `path` function for this:

```
<a href="{{ path('myBundle_apt', { 'aptId': usr.publisherId }) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOnbutton">ON</a>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. Add `}}` at the end of path twig function.